# In Angular 2 how do I scroll to a required field error on submit

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 how do I scroll to a required field error on submit.

I have the required tag on the input text box and on submit I want it to scroll up to the error.

This is mainly for mobile experience.

**Here's my form:**

```
     <form data-toggle="validator" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" role="form" #form2="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" autocomplete="off">                                                    

<input class="form-control-small col-xs-11 col-lg-4" id="JobName" type="text" placeholder="Name of Job" [(ngModel)]="job.name" required />

      <button [disabled]="!form2.form.valid" type="submit">Submit</button> 

    </form>
```

Comment: This will be a problem if you have many fields

Comment: Yeh I do, I have 10 in total

Comment: And if you have 5 errors at the same time? when to scroll?

Comment: Scroll to first one

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Angular directive to solve this problem. You can check it here [ngx-scroll-to-first-invalid](https://github.com/Ismaestro/ngx-scroll-to-first-invalid).

Steps:

1.Install the module:

```
npm i @ismaestro/ngx-scroll-to-first-invalid --save
```

2.Import the `NgxScrollToFirstInvalidModule`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {NgxScrollToFirstInvalidModule} from '@ismaestro/ngx-scroll-to-first-invalid';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgxScrollToFirstInvalidModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3.Use the directive inside a form:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" ngxScrollToFirstInvalid>
  <input id="test-input1" type="text" formControlName="someText1">
  <button (click)="saveForm()"></button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps!
:)